# How get items click on notification

Tags: java, android, notifications

How I can determine items where user click on my notification in Notification Bar?
I need know where user click:

- on left large icon
- on body (on title or on text line)
- on right small icon
- on right timestamp

I create BroadcastReceiver on click notification. I receive intent:
If print intent.toString() I see info:

```
Intent { act=com.mypackage2130837512 flg=0x10 bnds=[64,79][320,143] }
```

I see which the coordinates but its always constantly.

Please any ideas how get items click on notification?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not supported. Please use [standard `Notification` actions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Actions), for the main `Notification` body and, where supported, additional action buttons/controls.

Comment: Notification actions available after API 16, but what about android version иудщц 16?

Comment: @TapaSave: I have no idea what "android version иудщц 16" is. You are correct that notification actions are relatively new. However, what you want is not supported, and so you will need to limit yourself to responding to a single action for the whole `Notification` (`setContentIntent()` on your `Builder`) for earlier Android versions.

Comment: I'm sorry, transliteration... (иудщц == below). Thank you for answer, I will try use only single action on version below 16. It is possible create Notification with own Layout and few Views inside, and own OnClickListeners?

Comment: @TapaSave: "It is possible create Notification with own Layout and few Views inside, and own OnClickListeners?" -- not reliably. You can create your own custom `RemoteViews`, and you can set up `PendingIntents` to be invoked on clicks on widgets in there. However, officially, that wasn't supposed to work, and so whether it *does* work varies by device.